# Javascript to update progress bar, then switch visible div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page which is being generated through PHP web scraping. As the collection of the content causes a delay, I am trying to introduce a bootstrap progress bar whilst the loading is happening.

I am not linking the bar into any actual loading stages, I'm just running it for 3 seconds and then getting the code to hide/show the relevant div's (the first div contains the loading bar, the second contains the content).

I have the following code but the php-content div is appearing instantly rather than delaying. There is no output to the javascript console in chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loader").show();
        $("#php-content").hide();
        counter = 0;
        run();
    });

    function update(value) {
        $("#loadingBar").attr("style","width:"+value+"%");
        $("#loadingBar").attr("aria-valuenow",value);
    }

    function run() {
        if (counter <= 3000) {
            update(counter);
            counter+=10;
            setTimeout(run(), 10);
        } else {
            $("#loader").hide();
            $("#php-content").show();
        }

    }
</script>
```

And the HTML section:

```
<div id="loader">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div id="loadingBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="3000" style="width: 0%">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="php-content">
                <h2>Current Weather Conditions:</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <?php include 'php/scrape.php' ?>
                </table>
            </div>
```

UPDATE - Please see my Answer below. I found a solution after posting this question.

Answer (score 2):

I have some minor changes in your code, i think it's help you, here code below

Html code

```
<div id="loader">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div id="loadingBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="3000" style="width: 0%">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="php-content">
                <h2>Content:</h2>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    new content
                </table>
            </div>
```

Css Code

```
#loadingBar{background: red;float: left;min-height: 20px;}
#php-content{display:none;}
```

Jquery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#php-content").animate({'opacity' : '0'});
        jQuery("#loader").animate({'opacity' : '1'});
        counter = 0;        
        run();
    });

    function update(value) {
        jQuery("#loadingBar").animate({width:value+"px"});
        jQuery("#loadingBar").attr("aria-valuenow",value);
    }


    function run() {        
        if (counter <= 800) {
            jQuery("#loader").animate({'opacity' : '1'});
            jQuery("#php-content").animate({'opacity' : '0'});            
            update(counter);
            counter+=10;
            setTimeout(run(), 10);
        } else {            
            jQuery("#loader").animate({'opacity' : '0'});
            jQuery("#php-content").show();
            jQuery("#php-content").animate({'opacity' : '1'});
        }

    }
```

Demo link
http://jsfiddle.net/kishan_web/b2jzu4er/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on this tutorial here - [Animate Progress Bars with Jquery](http://www.doidea.se/techblog/animated-bootstrap-progress-bars-with-jquery)

Basically, I ended up simply setting the width of the progress bar to 100% using jquery's .attr() function. Using a css rule, the transition duration can be set to 3 seconds. All that needs to happen is to set a timeout in the code to stop doing anything else while the transition is happening.

Script (looking neater than before):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#loader").show();
    $("#php-content").hide();
    $("#loadingBar").attr("style", "width:100%");
    setTimeout(function() {$("#php-content").show();$("#loader").hide();}, 3000);
});
```

CSS:

```
.progress-bar {
-webkit-transition: width 3s ease-in-out;
transition: width 3s ease-in-out;
```

}